# t test in a data frame in R using mutate

Tags: r

I am struggling to compute a t-test between 2 groups in data frame in R. The sample code below produces a data frame with 2 columns: Variable and Value. There are 2 variables: "M" and "F".

```
data <- data.frame(variable = c("M", "F", "F"), value = c(10,5,6))
```

I need to show that the value for M and F are statistically different from each other. In other words, 10 is statistically different from the mean of 5 and 6. I need to add another column in this data frame that shows the p value. When I run the code below, it gives the following error:

```
result <- data %>% mutate(newcolumn = t.test(value~variable))
```

Error in t.test.default(x = c(5, 6), y = 10) : 
  not enough 'y' observations

Comment: Hi @xilliam I have added the code to produce a small sample dataset

Comment: The error is telling you it can't conduct a t-test because you don't have enough values. When one of the groups only has a single value, a t-test is not possible mathematically.

Comment: Thanks @IceCreamToucan,,yea I thought so..sorry my concepts are a little weak here..Initially I thought that a single value in a group can be compared against the mean of other values. Can you further explain why its not possible? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the question.

The test itself could be run as a one sample t test for the mean. It would be

```
t.test(x = c(5, 6) - 10)
```

If you want to test running a package `dplyr` pipe:

```
library(dplyr)

fun_t_test <- function(x){
  tryCatch(t.test(x)$p.value, error = function(e) NA)
}

data %>%
  mutate(newvalue = value - mean(value[variable == "M"])) %>%
  group_by(variable) %>%
  summarise(p.value = fun_t_test(newvalue))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  variable p.value
#  <fct>      <dbl>
#1 F         0.0704
#2 M        NA
```